# R: Elegant way to create this table

Tags: r

I'm looking for an elegant way to create a table of this data:

I have a vector of dates I am interested in

```
> date
[1] "2008-01-01" "2008-01-02" "2008-01-03" "2008-01-04" "2008-01-05"
```

and a table of data from wikipedia (views per day)

```
> changes
2007-08-14 2007-08-16 2007-08-17 2007-12-29 2008-01-01 2008-01-03 2008-01-05 
         4          1          4          1          1          1          2
```

What I want is a table with the data for the dates I am interested in

```
> mytable
2008-01-01 2008-01-02 2008-01-03 2008-01-04 2008-01-05
         1          0          1          0          2
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this elegantly?

---

Here is the output of *dput*:

```
> dput(date)
structure(c(13879, 13880, 13881, 13882, 13883), class = "Date")
```

and

```
> dput(changes)
structure(c(15L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Dim = 262L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
c("2007-08-14", "2007-08-16", 
"2007-08-17", "2007-12-29", "2008-01-01", "2008-01-03", "2008-01-05")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

Comment: Add the output of `dput(changes)` and `dput(date)`. It'll take all the guess work out of what *exactly* your data looks like. I'm guessing a vector and a named vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using `match` would be the easiest way. You need to use `as.character` to be able to match dates to the names of your  changes `table`...

```
#  Match dates in the names of 'changes' vector. No match gives NA
#  Using setNames we can return the object and set the names in one command
mytable <- setNames( changes[ match(as.character(date) , names(changes)) ] , date )

#  Change NA values to 0 (is this sensible? Does no data mean 0 views or was the data not available?)
mytable[ is.na(mytable) ] <- 0

mytable
#2008-01-01 2008-01-02 2008-01-03 2008-01-04 2008-01-05 
#         1          0          1          0          3
```